# How can I do something like "if (a > x > b)"?

Tags: javascript, if-statement

This might be a simple question but I'm having trouble getting it to work.
I'm trying to have a key interaction where, when pressed, its checks the location of the camera and does different things depending on where it is. 
Here's a chunk of it:

```
function onKeyDown (event) {
switch (event.keyCode) {

case 49: /*1*/ 
if (looking){                       

    //P1
    if (-36 < (camera.position.x) < -25) {if (-10 < (camera.position.z) < 10){
    //P1stuff
    looking = false,  text.innerHTML = "Painting1", controls.movementSpeed = 0, controls.rollSpeed = 0

} else{}
}
```

There's more below this in my actual project, and I've replaced the if statement's conditions so my code is all working fine, its just not reading my camera's locations when formatted in that "(a < (camera.position.x) < b)" way.
How would I go about typing and performing this kind of check for an if?

Comment: `if (x < y && y < z)` ? x,y,z not in direct reference to coordinate axes, here..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`(-36 < (camera.position.x) < -25)` is wrong, you're essentially doing the following

```
var foo = -36 < camera.position.x; // foo will be either true or false;
```

and then your second comparison is basically doing `true < -25`, which is not what you're wanting to accomplish.

What you need to do is split your comparators up: `((-36 < camera.position.x) && (camera.position.x < -25))`, like so:

```
function onKeyDown (event) {
    switch (event.keyCode) {
        case 49: /*1*/ 
            if (looking){                       

            //P1
            if (-36 < camera.position.x && camera.position.x < -25) {
                if (-10 < camera.position.z && camera.position.z < 10) {
                    //P1stuff
                    looking = false;  
                    text.innerHTML = "Painting1"; 
                    controls.movementSpeed = 0; 
                    controls.rollSpeed = 0
                 } else { }
            }
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

It should simply be split into two pieces of Boolean logic, combined with an AND operation.

```
// -36 < camera.position.x < -25 becomes two Boolean boundary conditions...

if (camera.position.x > -36 && camera.position.x < -25) {
    // do something
}
```

The camera position is the pertinent property that we're checking here, hence why it is most sensible to put it first in your logical checks.